# Write a Bash Script to edit a csv file

Tags: linux, bash

So i have a csv file like

```
Sam,0.0.1
Smith,0.0.1
```

I want to append

```
Ria,0.0.1
```

Final result should look like this

```
Sam,0.0.1
Smith,0.0.1
Ria,0.0.1
```

the command i used:

```
sed -i s/\'smith,0.0.1\'/\'smith,0.0.1\',\'Ria,0.01'\'/g <name of csv>
```

what it does is

```
Sam,0.0.1
Smith,0.0.1, Ria,0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `\n` before `Ria`.

The command should be:

```
sed -i s/'smith,0.0.1'/'smith,0.0.1','\nRia,0.01''/g
```

The `\n` indicates *new line*.

Comment: Quotes mess, and not working

Comment: Ok, with the quotes does not work

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
sed -i '$a Ria,0.0.1' file
```

- `$` stands for *last line*
- `a` stands for *append*

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do just that:

```
echo "Ria,0.0.1" >> csv_file
```